# How to fix Website-Available-Check in Python?

Tags: python, https

After having some issues with a website, I would like to have code running that checks every now and then if webiste is still available.

Here is the relevant snippet of code:

```
import urllib.request
print(urllib.request.urlopen("https://website.sharepoint.com").getcode())
```

My problem is that I can't get around the following Error: 
HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden

I found someways to check if the website exists and that worked, but not a working way to check if the website is available.

When I add headers to the request, I get the following Error:
TypeError: urlopen() got an unexpected keyword argument 'headers'

Comment: A 403 forbidden error means the webserver doesnt want to allow you to view the page. Often this is because the server doesn't recognise you as being logged in. Do you also get a 403 error if you open the same URL in an incognito/private browser session?

Comment: Hello, thank you for your explanation. 
If I open the website in an icognito session, I get to the login-page from microsoft.
But if the website is having issues again, it just shows the error "This Webpage is not available."

Comment: If you get a login page (e.g. a 200 HTTP response), in a browser but a 403 from the python code, then it's possible that the server is treating the `User-Agent` header differently. you could try getting your python code to set a user agent that looks like a common browser. I'd also recommend using the python `requests` package for doing this stuff, it's a little bit nicer than using `urllib`.